# During repo sync progress, regularly to appear the message: "invalid clone.bundle file; ignoring"

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm trying to port a new device for ubuntu-touch. During the progress, after a "repo sync" in terminal, it often appears the message: "Invalid clone.bundle file; ignoring".

I don't know what it is, and is the progress getting a potential failure, could you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

That message is not an error. The `clone.bundle` for that repository doesn't exist, so `repo` chose to ignore it.

I ran `repo` with `--trace` (verbose mode) and found an example `clone.bundle` file [hosted on Ubuntu's website](https://code-review.phablet.ubuntu.com/p/aosp/platform/manifest.git/clone.bundle). If you go to that link, you'll notice that it just redirects to a status page. **It's not acually a** `clone.bundle` **file!**

Now, to make sure that I'm not getting anything wrong, let's compare this webpage to another `clone.bundle` file [located on googlesource](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/clone.bundle). Notice how it is an actual file and downloads.